# How to push updated local JSON file to Firebase in swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I have updated my local JSON file but I cannot figure out why it is not being pushed to Firebase? For example, I created JSON file and used placeholder text just to see how it would look in the UI. I pushed the placeholder text to Firebase but when I updated my JSON file in Xcode, it did not get pushed and updated in Firebase. Do I need to make a new push method for that particular key/value pair?

Here is an example of what I pushed initially with the placeholder text

```
"id": 1,
        "category": "Cardiovascular",
        "course": {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "cardiovascular",
            "description": "This quiz goes over the cardiovascular system.",
```

Here is the update to description that I want to push to Firebase.

```
"id": 1,
        "category": "Cardiovascular",
        "course": {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "cardiovascular",
            "description": "The Cardiovascular system transports blood containing oxygen, nutrients, and other substances (e.g., hormones, electrolytes, and drugs) to the tissues of the body, whereas at the same time facilitating the removal of carbon dioxide and other waste products from the body. It also assists in temperature regulation. The primary components of the cardiovascular system include the heart, arteries, arterioles, capillaries, venules, veins, and blood. The heart is comprised of cardiac muscle and nervous tissue that fat generates the force that propels the blood through the body.",
```

Here is the method to push to Firebase

```
func pushToFirebase(quizmodules: [Quiz]){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        let firebaseModules = db.collection("quizmodules")
        
        for quiz in quizmodules {
            let course = quiz.course
            let test = quiz.course.test
            
            let firebaseModule = firebaseModules.addDocument(data: ["category": quiz.category])
            
            firebaseModule.updateData(["id": firebaseModule.documentID,
                                       "course": ["id": firebaseModule.documentID,
                                        "image": course.image,
                                                  "description": course.description,
                                                  
                                        ],
                                       "test": [
                                        "id": firebaseModule.documentID,
                                        "questions": test.questions.count
                                       ]
                                      ])
            
            
            
            
            for question in test.questions {
                let firebaseQuestion = firebaseModule.collection("questions").addDocument(data: ["content": question.content,
                                                                                                 "correctIndex": question.correctIndex,
                                                                                                 "answers": question.answers
                                                                                                 
                ])
                
                firebaseQuestion.updateData(["id": firebaseQuestion.documentID])
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate the question to make sure I am answering correctly:

> I am writing a document to Firestore and want to update that document
> at a later time

When you want to update a specific document in Firestore, you need to know the documentId of the document you want updated.

So here's the issue

```
let firebaseModule = firebaseModules.addDocument(data:
```

`.addDocument` creates a new document each time it's run so the following `.update` call updates the document that was just created. The next time the code is run a totally new document is created.

Also, and maybe this is intentional, the `.addDocument` call creates documents with a field `category`

```
["category": quiz.category])
```

and then just adds a bunch more fields to that same document.

```
firebaseModule.updateData(["id": firebaseModule.documentID,
                           "course": ["id": firebaseModule.documentID,
```

so every document looks the same

```
some_document_id
     category: some value
     course: [
              description: some value
```

that could be simplified by just creating the document with the fields in the `addDocument` call.

So - how to fix. Here's a very brief example that creates an initial document with a documentId of `my_document`

```
let tempCollection = self.db.collection("my_collection")
let myDocument = tempCollection.document("my_document")
myDocument.setData(["field0": "data0",
                    "field1": "data1"])
```

At a later time in your code, you want to update the values of `field0` and `field1` of `my_document`. Here's how to do that

```
let tempCollection = self.db.collection("my_collection")
let myDocument = tempCollection.document("my_document")
myDocument.updateData(["field0": "new data0",
                       "field1": "new data1"])
```

The important bit is that the document being updated **has the same documentId (my_document)** as in the code that created the document.

Comment: Thank you for the help! In general, is it easier just to update the key or value in Firebase instead?

Comment: @Kevin Keys are unique identifiers that are paired with a value, called key: value pairs. In Firestore those are referred to as Fields and values. In order to update a specific value, the path to the value must be known (which includes the Field name). This includes the collection name, the documentId, and the key (aka Field Name). That's illustrated in my answer; if we want to update field0, we would need to know the `/my_collection/my_document/field0`. So to address your question; 'easier' doesn't really apply - to perform that update, there's no other option. Does that answer your question?